# Redirecting output of program reading from stdin

Tags: shell, command-line, c

When I want to redirect an output of *a.out* program I will use

```
./a.out > output.txt
```

This doesn't work when the program reads something from *stdin*.
How would you redirect output in this case?

I can do it only with

```
./a.out < inputs.txt > output.txt
```

Can I do the same but reading inputs from *stdin*?

EDIT: I realized that it works, but I can't see prompts because everything goes to file *output.txt*. So, the only problem is to see prompts on *stdin* and preserve redirection at the same time.

Comment: I'm not a developer, so I'm not sure about convention, but don't prompts go to STDERR typically?  Alternatively, you can use the `tee` command, something like `./a.out |tee output.txt`

Comment: Tee is good but I can't see the prompts (printf statement in C) at the right moment.

Comment: @cjc no prompts typically go to stdout. But xralf can check if stdout is a terminal and if it is not a terminal print the prompt to stderr

Comment: If the prompts are sent to the same channel as the normal output, your program doesn't support what you're trying to do; it's probably badly designed. You would need to use a wrapper to filter the output between prompt and non-prompt. Use expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to write your prompts to `stderr` rather than `stdout`. They'll be visible on the terminal but not in `output.txt`.

Another option is not to use redirection for your output but take an output filename as a parameter and open that file yourself. You can then use `stdout` for your prompts. (This is more flexible. You can decide what goes only to the file, what goes only to the screen, and potentially what goes to both.)

If you can't change the code, the only option is to use `tee` or some other such utility. Buffering can be a problem; [`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) might help with that.

Comment: I'd like to rather don't change the application. Assume I have only binary (if it's even possible, maybe it's not possible).

Comment: Modifying the code is better. If you only have the binary, why did you tag this `c`, and why is your binary called `a.out`? cjc already gave you an option without modifying the code (inserted above too), that's pretty much all you have as options.